# Transaction for 2 dao in Room is real?

Tags: android, android-room

In `Room` have 2 tables/Dao - PoolDao and AccountDao with relation one-to-many (one pool many accounts). I need first create and save pool and after create and save (one or more) accounts.

How in room create transaction which operates with two Dao? 
In documentation i find only transaction for only one dao -
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can user runInTransaction option of your appDatabase object:

```
appDatabase.runInTransaction
{
    appDatabase.dao1.doWhatNeedsToBeDone()
    appDatabase.dao2.doWhatNeedsToBeDone()
}
```

You have example [here](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-room-database-transaction/).

Comment: Just a note to other devs looking to use transactions, you must throw an exception yourself when a query doesn't go according to plan for the rollback to happen. e.g. if insert returns a 0 when it fails to create a record, you throw an exception for it to rollback and undo all previous queries. This is the same when using @Transaction inside a Dao.